# sound play for any computers

Tags: c#, winforms

I use these following codes to play music while clicking the button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SoundPlayer s = new SoundPlayer();
        s.SoundLocation = @"f:\1.wav";
        s.Play();
    }
```

But these codes are only for my computer what should i do so that i can play this sound on the other computers like database. what should i do so that i can play this song in other computers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "play this sound on the other computers like database"?

Comment: Do you expect another computer that has no access to "f:\1.wav" to be able to play it?

Comment: i mean when i make a setup and want to use this application on the other computers it won't work cause the location is in my computer f:\1.wav. what should i do so that i can play this song on the other computers

Comment: Well, you need to copy that file to the other computer, together with your application. And have it in a location that is known (not every computer has an f drive). Search for how to install applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import the file in the project's resources and load it from there using

```
Properties.Resources.<name_of_resource>
```

In order to import something to the resources do the following (assuming you use Visual Studio 2010 - it is similar to other versions I think):

> In Visual Studio 2010 solution explorer, right click Properties -> Open -> Resources -> Add Resource -> Add Existing File

Note that when you will install your application later on other computers the resources will be installed as well.

In order to play the sound you need to do the following then:

```
SoundPlayer myPlayer = new SoundPlayer(yourNamespace.Properties.Resources.mySound);
myPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: so what should i do for the codes? how to play from resource?

Comment: I will add the code to my answer to be easier spotted. Check it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like, get the file content as Stream from the database

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like, get the file content as Stream from the database or remote system and pass the stream to the SoundPlayer instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the sounds in a subfolder of the applications and access them via file's relative path (I believe, but I'm going to look it up precisely, it's `Application.StartupPath` in a winforms environment).

Or you could make them resources (see gkaran89's answer).